Paragraph gets under the figure despite being above in code
I am trying to make the paragraph to be above the figure yet it is put below. Why ?
I have tried different figure options with no success.
\paragraph{Poniżej jest porównanie obrazów przed i po próbkowaniu}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{obrazki próbkowanie.png}
    \caption{Przykład strat jakości w próbkowaniu}
    \label{fig:obrazek}
\end{figure}


h usually generates a warning that it is changed to ht, the only reason to use figure is to allow it to be moved, so what you describe is the expected behaviour

note \paragraph is a section heading, but you appear to only have a heading and no text.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

In addition to the \paragraph comment, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497: "do not use a floating environment if you do not want it float".

As @DavidCarlisle has already observed in a comment, you should be providing some text to go along with the \paragraph-level header. As soon as you do so, LaTeX will place the contents of the figure environment where you expect it should go.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Poniżej jest porównanie obrazów przed i po próbkowaniu} 
bla bla bla ble ble ble bli bli bli

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{obrazki próbkowanie}
    \caption{Przykład strat jakości w próbkowaniu}
    \label{fig:obrazek}
\end{figure}
\end{document} 


As a minimum, one can use \hfill.

@JohnKormylo -- I have a hunch that the OP doesn't really want \paragraph{...} but, rather, \subsubsection*{...}. Let's see if the OP weighs in and provides some welcome information.
